# Не подключается include в php

Tags: php

Есть файлы index.php и footer.php находящиеся в одной папке.
В footer.php пробовал и с `<html>` и с `<?php` и с `echo` и просто текст. Никак не выводит. В index.php так же пробовал разные методы. В крайнем случае выводит весь код вместе с `<?php` или пустой экран. Работаю через OpenServer.
Как сделать правильно?

В index.php

```
<?php  
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `include './footer.php';`. Иначе попробуйте `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/footer.php';`

Answer (score 1):

У вас код правильный.
footer.php

```
<?php
    $test_var = 'Работает';
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    include 'footer.php';
    echo $test_var;
?>
```

и у меня все правильно работает... Перепроверьте в корневой ли папке домена лежат эти файлы, если нет, то к файлам нужно писать полный путь

```
define(ROOT, dirname(__FILE__)); //в главном файле, тот что в корне домена, определяем константу пути
include ROOT.'/папки.../footer.php';
```

Еще может быть у вас в файле footer.php могут быть ошибки php кода
Откройте его через `require_once();`, если там будет ошибка, то выполнение скрипта прекратится, а в случае с `include`, оно продолжит выполнятся, но без подключения footer.php...

Answer (score 0):

> В крайнем случае выводит весь код вместе с

Такое подозрение, что в OpenServer не настроен сайт/домен, и **PHP интерпретатор поэтому не может разобрать ваш код**. Откройте Настройки OpenServer -> вкладка Домены. Если у вас стоит автоматическое определение каталогов, то поставьте ручное. Сами добавьте ваш локальный домен, выберите папку с сайтом. Не забудьте перезапустить OpenServer.